# Specify time zone for JavaScript Date's non-UTF methods

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

Is there a way to force all the non-UTC methods of a JS Date object to return their results in a specified time zone, not that of the particular browser?

(I don't have a problem in creating a Date object of a correct time, as I'm creating them by passing a Unix timestamp.)